# oozie not supporting unix file move operations within it

Tags: unix, move, oozie, operations

I have a OOZIE scheduler and I have written some UNIX command within it which will move files from one folder to another in unix box.

But it is not working in the OOZIE and every time throwing error 'path not found'.

Please Note: I am using hadoop muti-node cluster

Comment: The whole point of Oozie is to run your job on random node(s) on the cluster. If you are targeting a specific *"Unix box"* then Oozie is not the right choice. Use good old CRON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run a Oozie Job, internally it will be a map-reduce job and the job will be running on any of the datanodes where it looks in that particular datanode for the file to move. If that datanode do not have the file, it throws the path not found.

The same code works on single cluster not on Multi-node cluster.

You can use Hadoop commands (copyFromLocal or put) to load the data or You can use Flume to load the same.